# How to handle missing args in shell script

Tags: shell

What's the "right" way to handle missing arguments in a shell script? Is there a pre-canned way to check for this and then throw an exception? I'm an absolute beginner.

Comment: It would help if we knew which shell?

Comment: if you are beginning begin with something better than some undefined shell you don't specify. Learn Python, there is nothing you can do with any shell you can't do with Python, it is portable and way easier to do sophisticated things, it also has very good command line option parsing support built in ( batteries included )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

getopts is useful here: [getopts](http://rsalveti.wordpress.com/2007/04/03/bash-parsing-arguments-with-getopts/)

Comment: What makes you assume he uses bash? The proper link is http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/getopts.html

Comment: https://roperzh.github.io/grapse/

Answer (score 73):

Typical shell scripts begin by parsing the options and arguments passed on the command line. The number of arguments is stored in the `#` parameter, i.e., you get it with `$#`. For example, if your scripts requires exactly three arguments, you can do something like this:

```
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$0: not enough arguments"
  exit 2
elif [ $# -gt 3 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "$0: too many arguments"
  exit 2
fi
# The three arguments are available as "$1", "$2", "$3"
```

The built-in command `exit` terminates the script execution. The integer argument is the return value of the script: 0 to indicate success and a small positive integer to indicate failure (a common convention is that 1 means “not found” (think grep) and 2 means “unexpected error” (unrecognized option, invalid input file name, ...)).

If your script takes options (like `-x`), use [getopts](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/getopts.html).

Comment: @JW. No reason. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 21):

Example script (myscript.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

file1=${1?param missing - from file.}
file2=${2?param missing - to file.}  
[...]
```

Example:

```
$ ./myscript.sh file1 
./myscript.sh: line 4: 2: param missing - to file.
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is bash-specific.

Comment: This is described at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 15):

The `nounset` option will make bash treat unset variables and parameters as an error.

Example script (`myscript.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o nounset

echo First argument: $1
echo OK
```

Example:

```
$ ./myscript.sh; echo $?
./myscript.sh: line 4: $1: unbound variable
1
$ ./myscript.sh foo; echo $?
First argument: foo
OK
0
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, and is much simpler than the accepted answer

Comment: Simple, this should be an accepted answer

Answer (score -2):

In my case I was using `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` which didn't like `-o KEY Value`, it wants

```
ssh -o KEY=value
```

ref https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1299